# what is wrong with this code i am trying to translate nav using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

i want to change the nav elements when click the buttons using jquery, i created json object and added the jquery script, but i don't know why it is not working ?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>


  <li class="lang" key="home">Home</li>
  <li class="lang" key="about">About Us</li>
  <li class="lang" key="contact">Contact Us</li>


  <button class="translate" id="en">English</button>
  <button class="translate" id="ar">عربي</button>
```

this is the json object

```
  <script>
  var arrLang = {
    'en': {

      'home': 'Home',
      'about': 'About us',
      'contact': 'contact us'
    },

    'ar': {

      'home': 'الصفحة الرئيسية',
      'about': 'عن الشركة',
      'contact': 'اتصل بنا'
    }
  };
```

this is the script of jquery

```
  $(function() {
    $('.translate').click(function() {
      var lang = $(this).attr('id');

      $('lang').each(function(index, element) {

        $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr('key')]);

      });

    });

  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to translate the nave elements using jquery, but i don't know what is wrong with this code ?

Comment: Are you missing a dot in your script? `$('.lang')` instead of `$('lang')`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `.lang` as selector since `lang` is a class.

```js
var arrLang = {
  'en': {'home': 'Home','about': 'About us','contact': 'contact us'},
  'ar': {'home': 'الصفحة الرئيسية','about': 'عن الشركة','contact': 'اتصل بنا'}
};

$('.translate').click(function() {
  var lang = $(this).attr('id');

  $('.lang').each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr('key')]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="lang" key="home">Home</li>
  <li class="lang" key="about">About Us</li>
  <li class="lang" key="contact">Contact Us</li>
</ul>

<button class="translate" id="en">English</button>
<button class="translate" id="ar">عربي</button>
```

Comment: Happy to help @al3dwy